# PUT to writable bucket: 400

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

During testing I made my bucket public (in the future users will upload their files here - and Lambda will download them):
[image: s3 Permissions]

My CORS is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

My JS is:

```
input.onchange = function() {
    fetch('https://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/', {
        'method': 'PUT',
        'body': this.files[0]
    })
}
```

But response from S3 is 400 without explanation. Before PUT I see successful OPTIONS. In the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html) I see only one required header - `Content-Length` - and browser add it.

Comment: Note that this is an extremely dangerous idea, and an excellent way to run up unexpected charges on your billing.  The user who uploads the object is the user that owns the object -- not you.  I can put objects in your bucket that you cannot access, but you'll still get the bill for storage and downloads.

Answer (score 0):

URL! You must specify **filename** like

`https://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/myfile.jpg`